# In python, what is a character buffer?

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite

I am a beginner SQLite user and has run into some trouble, hoping to find someone who could help.

I am trying to read some data out of a database, put it into a variable in python and print it out onto a HTML page.

The table inside the database is calle "Status", it contains two columns "stamp" and "messages". "stamp is an INT containing a time stamp, and "messages" contains a TEXT.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def comment(self, ID = None):
    con = lite.connect('static/database/Status.db')
    output = ""
    with con:    
        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Status WHERE stamp = ?", (ID,))
        temp = cur.fetchone()
        output = temp[0]

    comments = self.readComments(ID)


    page = get_file(staticfolder+"/html/commentPage.html")
    page = page.replace("$Status", output)
```

The error I am getting reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond
    cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 25, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "proj1base.py", line 184, in comment
    page = page.replace("$Status", output)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me clarify what a character buffer object is, and how do i use one in order for my code to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace "character buffer" by "string" for starters.  (There are more types exposing the "buffer protocol" in Python, but don't bother with them for now.)  Most likely, `output` ended up not being a string.  Log its type in the line before the error.

Comment: Thank you, i realize it's type INT, which means it's being assigned the col "stamp" instead of "messages". Once I fixed that, it all worked fine. Thank you very much.